# TileControl.ItemClick event vs TileControl.ItemPress event

Tags: vb.net, events, devexpress, controls

I'm trying to figure out what the difference of a *click* and a *press* event on a devexpress tile control is.

According to the [online documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsTileControlClassEventsTopic):

---

> [TileControl.ItemClick](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsTileControl_ItemClicktopic) Event Fires when an end-user clicks a TileItem
>   within the TileControl.
>
> ...
>
> **Remarks**
>   Handle the ItemClick event to respond to an end-user clicking any item
>   within the current TileControl object. You can also use handle the
>   TileItem.ItemClick event to respond to clicking an individual
>   TileItem. This event can be raised in code via the
>   TileItem.PerformItemClick method. The TileItem.ItemClick event is
>   fired before the ItemClick event.
>
> The ItemClick event comes after the ItemPress event when the left
>   mouse button is released. If an item is being dragged, the ItemClick
>   event is never fired.

' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '

> [TileControl.ItemPress](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsTileControl_ItemPresstopic)  Event Fires when an end-user presses a TileItem within the current
>   TileControl.
>
> ...
>
> **Remarks**
>   Tile items have two event types to respond to an end-user clicking
>   them at runtime: item press and item click events. Immediately after
>   an end-user clicks a tile item, tile item press events are fired.
>   First, the TileItem.ItemPress event is raised. After that, the
>   ItemPress event is fired.

---

This is probably very obvious to a more experienced developer but I'm very confused about this and don't understand when to use click/press. When should I use "[ItemPress](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsTileControl_ItemPresstopic)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in vb.net when a control is clicked, it means that you have fired two events, the mousedown and the mouseup event and i think, in your case, and as mentioned in the documentation, ItemClick Remark int last section:

> The ItemClick event comes after the ItemPress event when the left
>   mouse button is released. If an item is being **dragged**, the
>   ItemClick event is **never** fired.

when you release the mouse left button after pressing it, and if you have not dragged the Tile Item an Itemclick event will be fired, else the ItemPress event will be pressed.